# Passing submitted form data to another component

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code, it basically accepts some basic input and when submit button is clicked user is notified with an alert, state is constantly being updated via onChange event. What i wonder is can i somehow pass the retrieved data to another component inside the event handler for submit button (which i have called handleFormSubmit)? I have recently seen react has something called 'context' ...maybe that would be best here? Advice please? :)

```js
class Form extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
             username: '',
             comments: '',
             topic: 'react'
        }

        this.handleUsernameChange = this.handleUsernameChange.bind(this);
        this.handleCommentsChange = this.handleCommentsChange.bind(this);
        this.handleTopicChange = this.handleTopicChange.bind(this);
        this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleUsernameChange(event){
        this.setState({
            username: event.target.value
        },
        () =>{
            console.log(this.state.username)
        })
    }

    handleCommentsChange(event){
        this.setState({
            comments: event.target.value
        },
        () =>{
            console.log(this.state.comments)
        })
    }

    handleTopicChange(event){
        this.setState({
            topic: event.target.value
        },
        () =>{
            console.log(this.state.topic)
        })
    }

    handleFormSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        alert(`${this.state.username} ${this.state.comments} ${this.state.topic}`);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type='text' value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleUsernameChange}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <textarea value={this.state.comments} onChange={this.handleCommentsChange}></textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <select value={this.state.topic} onChange={this.handleTopicChange}>
                        <option value="react">React</option>
                        <option value="angular">Angular</option>
                        <option value="vue">Vue</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You can see formik[https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik]. It has a lot of functionalities

Comment: @Ciaran Whyte you want to handle input changes from child component ? correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Yes you can, depends upon where to want to pass data to. If parent child relationship then through props, otherwise through context or redux.

Comment: HI @tarzenchugh okay cool im very new to react so ill have to investigate context a little more. Give me moment i may try something with conditional rendering and additional state attribute will upload in a moment

Answer (score 1):

Hi all i made some changes and got something working, added extra state attribute called dataSubmitted set it to false then only after i submit the data is child (which i called AcceptFormData) allowed to render and i pass the state attributes as props. I do not know if this is a good approach or not but it works and no console errors.

```
class Form extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
             username: '',
             comments: '',
             topic: 'react',
             dataSubmitted: false
        }

        this.handleUsernameChange = this.handleUsernameChange.bind(this);
        this.handleCommentsChange = this.handleCommentsChange.bind(this);
        this.handleTopicChange = this.handleTopicChange.bind(this);
        this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleUsernameChange(event){
        this.setState({
            username: event.target.value
        },
        () =>{
            console.log(this.state.username)
        })
    }

    handleCommentsChange(event){
        this.setState({
            comments: event.target.value
        },
        () =>{
            console.log(this.state.comments)
        })
    }

    handleTopicChange(event){
        this.setState({
            topic: event.target.value
        },
        () =>{
            console.log(this.state.topic)
        })
    }

    handleFormSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({
            dataSubmitted: true
        })
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.dataSubmitted === false){
            return (
                <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
                    <div>
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input type='text' value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleUsernameChange}/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <textarea value={this.state.comments} onChange={this.handleCommentsChange}></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <select value={this.state.topic} onChange={this.handleTopicChange}>
                            <option value="react">React</option>
                            <option value="angular">Angular</option>
                            <option value="vue">Vue</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <button>Submit</button>
                </form>
            )
        }else{
            return (
                <AcceptFormData username={this.state.username} comments={this.state.comments} topic={this.state.topic}/>
            )
        }
    }
}

export default Form
```